# three.js: custom geometry wont be textured

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made two custom geometries: `Box2Geometry` and `StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry`.

The first will texturize just fine, as can be seen in this [Box2Geometry JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loldrup/fttpjkkw/).
The second won't texturize, as can be seen in this [StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loldrup/pb6pLseq/)
(do note that the fiddles load a bit slowly).
The two fiddles are basically identical, except for the different geometries. The material for the `StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry` has been given `emissive: 0xffffff` as argument, but removing this property doesn't solve the problem.

For completeness sake, I've also made a [third fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loldrup/j54oqsqf/), with the intention of demonstrating both geometries in action simultaneously. However, this fiddle fails to render anything, and I think the computing gods are surely laughing right now.

**Rendering output from the Box2Geometry fiddle:**

[image: Output of Box2 fiddle]

**Rendering output from the StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry fiddle:**

[image: Rendering from StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry fiddle]

**The well behaved code from the Box2Geometry fiddle:**

```js
"use strict";

// make DOM elements:
var container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
container.appendChild( info );

// create scene:
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// make the 'Box2' geometry, and its corresponding texture and mesh:
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";
loader.load("http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif",
 function ( texture ) {
        var myBox2geom = new THREE.Box2Geometry( 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10 );  // args: x,y,z-dimensions and width of their segments
  texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
  var myBox2mesh = new THREE.Mesh(myBox2geom, material);
  scene.add( myBox2mesh );
 },
 function () {},  // onProgress function
 function ( error ) { console.log( error ) }  // no error gets logged
);

// make light:
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set(0, 0, 300);
light.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
scene.add( light );

// make camera:
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
scene.add( camera );

// make renderer:
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// aaaand render, continuously!
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();


THREE.Box2Geometry = function ( width, height, depth, widthSegments, heightSegments, depthSegments ) {

 THREE.Geometry.call( this );

 this.parameters = {
  width: width,
  height: height,
  depth: depth,
  widthSegments: widthSegments,
  heightSegments: heightSegments,
  depthSegments: depthSegments
 };

 this.widthSegments = widthSegments || 1;
 this.heightSegments = heightSegments || 1;
 this.depthSegments = depthSegments || 1;

 var constructee = this;  // constructee = the instance currently being constructed by the Box2Geometry constructor

 var width_half = width / 2;    // width  = the distance along x in the absolute 3D space
 var height_half = height / 2;  // height = the distance along y in the absolute 3D space
 var depth_half = depth / 2;    // depth  = the distance along z in the absolute 3D space

 buildPlane( 'z', 'y', -1, -1, depth, height, width_half, 0 ); // px
 buildPlane( 'z', 'y',  1, -1, depth, height, -width_half, 1 ); // nx
 buildPlane( 'x', 'z',  1,  1, width, depth, height_half, 2 ); // py
 buildPlane( 'x', 'z',  1, -1, width, depth, -height_half, 3 ); // ny
 buildPlane( 'x', 'y',  1, -1, width, height, depth_half, 4 ); // pz
 buildPlane( 'x', 'y', -1, -1, width, height, -depth_half, 5 ); // nz

 function buildPlane( u, v, uDir, vDir, uDist, vDist, wDist_half, materialIndex ) {

  var w, iu, iv,
   segU = constructee.widthSegments,  // number of segments along u   // width  = x
   segV = constructee.heightSegments, // number of segments along v   // height = y
   uDist_half = uDist / 2,  // the extent of the plane along u, divided by two
   vDist_half = vDist / 2,  // the extent of the plane along v, divided by two
   offset = constructee.vertices.length;

  if ( ( u === 'x' && v === 'y' ) || ( u === 'y' && v === 'x' ) ) {

   w = 'z';

  } else if ( ( u === 'x' && v === 'z' ) || ( u === 'z' && v === 'x' ) ) {

   w = 'y';
   segV = constructee.depthSegments;

  } else if ( ( u === 'z' && v === 'y' ) || ( u === 'y' && v === 'z' ) ) {

   w = 'x';
   segU = constructee.depthSegments;

  }

  var segUi = segU + 1,  // i = inc = incremented (by one)
   segVi = segV + 1,  // i = inc = incremented (by one)
   segmentDist_u = uDist / segU,
   segmentDist_v = vDist / segV,
   normal = new THREE.Vector3();

  normal[ w ] = wDist_half > 0 ? 1 : -1;

  for ( iv = 0; iv < segVi; iv++ ) {

   for ( iu = 0; iu < segUi; iu++ ) {

    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex[ u ] = ( iu * segmentDist_u - uDist_half ) * uDir;
    vertex[ v ] = ( iv * segmentDist_v - vDist_half ) * vDir;
    vertex[ w ] = wDist_half;

    constructee.vertices.push( vertex );

   }

  }

  for ( iv = 0; iv < segV; iv++ ) {

   for ( iu = 0; iu < segU; iu++ ) {

    var a = iu         + segUi *   iv;
    var b = iu         + segUi * ( iv + 1 );
    var c = ( iu + 1 ) + segUi * ( iv + 1 );
    var d = ( iu + 1 ) + segUi *   iv;

    var uva = new THREE.Vector2(   iu       / segU, 1 -   iv       / segV );
    var uvb = new THREE.Vector2(   iu       / segU, 1 - ( iv + 1 ) / segV );
    var uvc = new THREE.Vector2( ( iu + 1 ) / segU, 1 - ( iv + 1 ) / segV );
    var uvd = new THREE.Vector2( ( iu + 1 ) / segU, 1 -   iv       / segV );

    var face1 = new THREE.Face3( a + offset, b + offset, d + offset );
    face1.normal.copy( normal );
    face1.vertexNormals.push( normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone() );
    face1.materialIndex = materialIndex;

    constructee.faces.push( face1 );
    constructee.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [ uva, uvb, uvd ] );

    var face2 = new THREE.Face3( b + offset, c + offset, d + offset );
    face2.normal.copy( normal );
    face2.vertexNormals.push( normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone() );
    face2.materialIndex = materialIndex;

    constructee.faces.push( face2 );
    constructee.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [ uvb.clone(), uvc, uvd.clone() ] );

   }

  }

 }

 this.mergeVertices();
};
THREE.Box2Geometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The dysfunctional code from the StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry fiddle:**

```js
"use strict";

// make DOM elements:
var container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
container.appendChild( info );

// create scene:
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// make the 'PentagonPlane' geometry, and its corresponding texture and mesh:
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";
loader.load("http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif",
 function ( texture ) {
  var myStaticTestPentagonPlane_geometry = new THREE.StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry();
  texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide, emissive: 0xffffff } );  // removing 'emissive' doesn't solve the problem
  var myStaticTestPentagonPlane_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(myStaticTestPentagonPlane_geometry, material);
  scene.add( myStaticTestPentagonPlane_mesh );
 },
 function () {},  // onProgress function
 function ( error ) { console.log( error ) }  // no error gets logged
);

// make light:
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set(0, 0, 300);
light.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
scene.add( light );

// make camera:
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
scene.add( camera );

// make renderer:
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// aaaand render, continuously!
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();


THREE.StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry = function () {

 THREE.Geometry.call(this);

 var quintuplet =  // static vertices of the PentagonPlaneGeometry
  [
   new THREE.Vector3(-50, -50, 51 ),
   new THREE.Vector3(-50,  50, 51 ),
   new THREE.Vector3( 50,  50, 51 ),
   new THREE.Vector3( 70,   0, 51 ),
   new THREE.Vector3( 50, -50, 51 )
  ];

 var constructee = this;  // constructee = the instance currently being constructed by the StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry constructor

 // Vertices must always be ordered clockwise, seen from outside the quadPlane

 var q = quintuplet;

 // populate the vertex array:
 constructee.vertices.push(q[0]);
 constructee.vertices.push(q[1]);
 constructee.vertices.push(q[2]);
 constructee.vertices.push(q[3]);
 constructee.vertices.push(q[4]);

 // previously calculated, and since manually pasted, faceVertexUvs:
 var uv0 = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
 var uv1 = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0.8333333333333334);
 var uv2 = new THREE.Vector2(0.8333333333333334, 0.8333333333333334);
 var uv3 = new THREE.Vector2(1, 0.4166666666666667);
 var uv4 = new THREE.Vector2(0.8333333333333334, 0.8333333333333334);

 // construct faces:

 var q0 = 0,  q1 = 1,  q2 = 2,  q3 = 3,  q4 = 4;

 // make plane normal:
 var planeVec1 = q[0].clone().sub(q[1]);
 var planeVec2 = q[0].clone().sub(q[2]);
 var normal    = planeVec1.cross(planeVec2).normalize();

 // create faces:
 var face1 = new THREE.Face3(q0, q4, q3);
 constructee.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push([ uv0, uv4, uv3 ]);  // alt: a d e
 face1.normal.copy( normal );
 face1.vertexNormals.push( normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone() );

 var face2 = new THREE.Face3(q0, q3, q1);
 constructee.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push([ uv0.clone(), uv3.clone(), uv1 ]);
 face2.normal.copy( normal );
 face2.vertexNormals.push( normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone() );

 var face3 = new THREE.Face3(q1, q3, q2);
 constructee.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push([ uv1.clone(uv1), uv3.clone(), uv2 ]);
 face3.normal.copy( normal );
 face3.vertexNormals.push( normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone(), normal.clone() );

 constructee.faces.push(face1);
 constructee.faces.push(face2);
 constructee.faces.push(face3);

 this.mergeVertices();
};
THREE.StaticTestPentagonPlaneGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Geometry.prototype);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="three.js"></script> -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your face normals point to wrong direction (0, 0, -1). So you can correct the `normal` calculation like this:

```
normal.z *= -1;
```

or as a more general solution, you can interchange the arguments for the `.cross` function call. This code:

```
var normal    = planeVec1.cross(planeVec2).normalize();
```

then becomes this:

```
var normal    = planeVec2.cross(planeVec1).normalize();
```

Finally, you could simply ask three.js to calculate face normals for you:

```
constructee.computeFaceNormals ();
```

You need to remove emissive component to make it work.

Comment: One more thing: You need to add only 3 vertex normals to a Face3, not the all 5 in this case.